# Coredata - array of fetchedobjects empty when called from other class

Tags: objective-c, arrays, core-data, initialization, class-method

From the - viewDidLoad () of a UIViewController class (called StageDetailViewController) I am calling an instance method on another class (called ContentController).

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        ContentController * instance = nil;
        instance = [[ContentController alloc] init];
        [instance fetchSectorList];
        [instance release];

       ....other stuff ....

}
```

The called method (fetchSectorList) looks like this:

```
- (void)fetchSectorList {

     NSLog(@"fetchSectorList method called");

     NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                               entityForName:@"Sectors" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
     [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
      NSError *error;
      NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

      for (NSManagedObject *info in fetchedObjects) {
           NSLog(@"aircraft in fetchsectorlist: %@", [info valueForKey:@"aircraft"]);
      }

[fetchRequest release]; 

}
```

The method is of type void simply because at this stage all I want to do is call it and ensure that it has some valid contents.

Here is the problem: When I call (void)fetchSectorList from StageDetailViewController, the NSLog file confirms that it has been called:

"fetchSectorList method called"

... but the for loop does not return anything!

HOWEVER, when I call the (void)fetchSectorList internally from within the ContentController class, a list of "aircraft" are returned by the for loop.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)stageResultsController {
    [self fetchSectorList];
    return [self resultsControllerForEntity:@"Stage"];
}
```

Why then can I not call this same method from another class? Please help. All contributions very welcome.

Notes:

1) I declare NSManagedObjectModel, NSManagedObjectContext and NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorin ContentController.h
2) I inherited the skeleton for the core data code from an example on the internet. It defines a class method that is used by another class in the example to init the class.

```
+ (ContentController *)sharedInstance {
    static ContentController * instance = nil;
    if (!instance) {
        instance = [[ContentController alloc] init];
```

I however am choosing to initialise from the initialiser code shown above in the viewdidload () of my calling class (StageDetailViewController). Could this be part of the problem?

Thanks for your patience. I'd really appreciate some input here. I'd be happy to provide clarification of any of the above.

**Solution!!!**

Guys, thanks for all the advice. Following Marcus's comments I delved a little deeper into Singletons and the call that gives the desired result from StageDetailViewController in -viewdidload() is simply:

[[ContentController sharedInstance] fetchSectorList];

The Singleton in my app:

- (ContentController *)sharedInstance

... will always have been initialised by the time the StageDetailViewController is initialised, and so being a singleton, it only needs to be initialised once in the runtime of the app. So a simple call to the fetchSectorList method works.

Marcus, sorry to associate your name with Singletons ... I vow to widen my armoury at a later stage.

Comment: I suggest you mark an answer as correct or add one of your own and mark it as correct.  Otherwise this question will be left open and eventually count against you.

Comment: Thanks Marcus. I tried to just after getting the solution, but the site prevented me doing this within 8 hours of registering the problem ... as I'm a new user. Will try again now.

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use Singletons.  Invest the time to learn about dependency injection designs.

Second, you are not using the singleton properly.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        ContentController * instance = nil;
        instance = [[ContentController alloc] init];
        [instance fetchSectorList];
        [instance release];

       ....other stuff ....

}
```

In this code you are not using a singleton.  You are creating an object, executing a method on it and then destroying it.  Therefore it won't have any values.

Change this code to:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        ContentController * instance = [ContentController sharedInstance];
        [instance fetchSectorList];

       ....other stuff ....

}
```

And you will get your desired results I suspect.

### Update 1

Do you have anything in the persistent store?

Does `self.managedObjectContext` return an actual object or is it nil?

Comment: Hi Marcus, thank you for your comments. Much appreciated. I ran the corrected singleton code (remarks noted!) and unfortunately it just did as before :remote method was called, but that no values returned within the for loop.

Comment: @LeeBarringer Answer is updated with some questions to debug this.

Comment: Marcus, thanks. I tested this by putting a simple if (self.managedobjectcontext != nil){...} around an NSLog, and in both cases (empty and full array) the self.managedobjectcontext was NOT nil. Total headache.

Comment: Hi Marcus, found the solution ... see inline with the problem statement ... thanks for all the help! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you are creating a new ContentController object, but you are not giving it a managed object context. So your call to the context to execute the fetch request will be passed to nil, so you get no results.

Unless you are lazily creating it for within the accessor, in which case the problem might be there? I can't tell from the code you have in the question.  Please put a breakpoint in the fetchSectorList and check the values of all the core data players for the working and non-working runs.

Comment: Thanks for this. I placed break points in the code for the two cases and the managed object context looked the same in each case. I cannot post images unfortunately as this website prevents new users from uploading them for spamming reasons :-( ... The only difference was of course that the array in the sucessful case had two members, and the failed case no members ...

Comment: Its probably my ignorance, as a newbie, but when I alloc init the ContentController, I thought I would automatically get a managed object context? The context is declared in the header, and implemented       as a method of ContentController.

Comment: Hi!, found the solution ... see inline with the problem statement ... thanks for all the help! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the advice. Following Marcus's comments I delved a little deeper into Singletons and the call that gives the desired result from StageDetailViewController in -viewdidload() is simply:

[[ContentController sharedInstance] fetchSectorList];

The Singleton in my app:

- (ContentController *)sharedInstance

... will always have been initialised by the time the StageDetailViewController is initialised, and so being a singleton, it only needs to be initialised once in the runtime of the app. So a simple call to the fetchSectorList method works.

Marcus, sorry to associate your name with Singletons ... I vow to widen my armoury at a later stage.